# Remove ListBoxItem on button click through ICommands

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I just started with XAML/WPF and there are lots of questions going on in my head. One of them is how do we bind a button click to remove a `ListBoxItem` through the ICommand interface. I created a simple WPF project and here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="129" Margin="15,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="314" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox Margin="5,5" Height="18" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </CheckBox>
                            <Button Content="[x]" Height="22" Width="22" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                    Command="{Binding ElementName=lb, Path=DataContext.DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Foo" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Bar" />
</ListBox>
```

And here's my Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Context(); // Also tried before InitializeComponent()
    }

    public class Context
    {
        public ICommand DeleteItemCommand = new DeleteItemCommand();
    }
}
```

Where `DeleteItemCommand` is:

```
public class DeleteItemCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Meep");
    }
}
```

The questions are:

1. Why isn't the message box showing? How do I make it work?
2. How do I retrieve which index/`ListBoxItem` triggered the button
   click?
3. How do I align the button to the end of the line?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have there is your ICommand is just a variable.

You need a public property in order to bind.

More like

```
    public ICommand DeleteItemCommand {get;set;} = new DeleteItemCommand();
```

Another problem is your elementname. This is subject to namescope and I think you'll find the listbox is in another namescope.

Instead, just use relativesource binding with ancestortype ListBox.

Roughly.

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItemCommand,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

As an aside.

I recommend looking into a framework to make commands and suchlike easier.

MVVMLight would be my suggestion. Add to a project using nuget mvvmlightlibs.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn237302.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The following is based on some code I already had so it's illustrative rather than exactly what you're doing.

View:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    <Button Content="Delete"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.DeletePersonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Viewmodel uses relaycommand from mvvmlight

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace wpf_99
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand<Person> deletePersonCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Person> DeletePersonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return deletePersonCommand
            ?? (deletePersonCommand = new RelayCommand<Person>(
              (person) =>
              {
                  People.Remove(person);
              }
             ));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set { people = value; }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Chesney", LastName = "Brown" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Gary", LastName = "Windass" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Liz", LastName = "McDonald" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Carla", LastName = "Connor" });
    }
}
}
```

BaseViewModel is pretty much as the msdn article on inotifypropertychanged shows:

```
public  class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Mvvmlight has its own base viewmodel but you can't serialise a vm inherits from that.

Person:
     public class Person : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string firstName;

```
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private string lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Andy! Thanks for the reply. Giving accessors to the command made it work. Are there any workarounds for this ugly `RelativeSource` thing?! Also, how do I align the button to the absolute right? And.... how do I retrieve the button's ListBoxItem index?

Comment: You realise each thread is supposed to be just one question? Relativesource - you could possibly make the datacontext a resource but I'd suggest you get past thinking it looks ugly. At least for now. Use a grid with columns rather than stackpanel if you want something over on the right and something on the left. Don't use index, pass the row viewmodel to the command CommandParameter="{Binding}"

Comment: I'm relative new to WPF and a complete sample would be the best. It doesn't make any sense in this case to create multiple threads about the same context. Also, I don't know how to "pass the row viewmodel to the command".